# How to read only the latest replied email text in javamail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mime-message

Read only the latest replied email text.

```
----------
I am good 

  On Saturday 27 January 2018 10:32 AM, xyz.sms wrote:   
   ----hello sai how are you ?
```

How to retrieve "i am good" ?  Any direct way to retrieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard for this.  It's just a string.  You have to guess what part of the string is an included or referenced message and which part is the reply.  Different mailers use different techniques to include the original message in the body of a reply message.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am using multi part  and putting all the old messages  in one part and the new in another.Also setting the part description as "old" and "new" so i can get in a conversation manner.Is it okay ?

Comment: If your program is the only one sending and receiving the messages, that's fine, but your messages probably won't display as expected in other mailers.

Comment: Thank you  , no other mailers will check.